# Relating KL Divergence Bounds to L1 norm bounds

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions

Consider that I have four distributions, $\varphi_1$, $\varphi_2$, $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$. Suppose that I know that for these distributions:

$$D_{KL}(\varphi_1||\varphi_2) \le D_{KL}(\psi_1||\psi_2)$$

Can I say, then, that the L1 distance between them follows the same "order"? That is:

$$||\varphi_1 - \varphi_2||_1 \le ||\psi_1 - \psi_2||_1$$

I know that the KL Divergence and L1 norm can be related by the bound $|| \varphi - \psi ||_1 \le \sqrt{ 2 \ln 2 D_{KL}(\varphi||\psi)}$, but it does not seem to be enough to prove the inequality above (if it is indeed true).

Comment: I don't see why that would be true. A stupid counter-example would be the one point set with $\varphi_1=20,\varphi_2=17,\psi_1=3,\psi_2=1$. Then $20\log(20/17)\leq 3\log 3$ but $|20-17|=3 > |3-1|=2$.